# How can i call multiple api at a same time in one controller

Tags: swift, swift5

I need call three API one after another in same view controller.these three API called after every 10 min. And the first api call's response use as parameter to third api call.

func a(){}

func b(){}

Func c(){}

Is there a way to call these api synchronously.
I want to call first func a then b and c.
How can i can implement the logic ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write three functions, `call1()`, `call2()`, and `call3()`. Have each one take a completion handler:

That might look something like this:

```
typealias networkCompletion = (Data) -> Void
func call1(callCompletion: networkCompletion) {
    //set up a URLSessionDataTask in `myDataTask`
    myDataTask.run() { result in
       switch result
       {
       case success(data):
         callCompletion(result.data)
       }
       case error: 
         //error handling
    {
}

//And so on for call2 and call3...


//Then have the completion handler for call1 call call3, 
//and the completion handler for call2 call call3:

call1() { call1Data in
  call2(call1Data) { call2Data in
    call3(call2Data)  { call3Data in
      //Call3 is complete. You've got your final data in call3Data
  }
}
```

Comment: So it does. Fixed.